# Stuck in neutral; throwout bearing still applied?

Tags: clutch, brake-fluid, clutch-cylinder

So, rebuilt a dodge neon.  Started driving it and felt fine. Made it about 7 blocks and I hear a light click and then I'm coasting. Still goes into gears just fine, but it seems like the clutch is stuck compressed.  I hear the faint sound of what I believe is the throwout bearing rotating.

So thinking what may have caused this I realized:
silly me forgot to check the brake fluid(Never messed with the brakes while fixing it up)  The brake fluid reservoir is for both the brakes and the clutch.

So my question is.  If it is the case of low brake fluid(havent checked yet).  Would putting fluid in(but not bleeding).  Be able to get me to limp it home?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Are you feeling any resistance when you press the pedal?

Comment: Usually, low brake fluid causes an obvious symptom - poor brakes, or no brakes at all! If the clutch bearing has just "stuck," giving the clutch housing a few blows with a hammer might free it temporarily. But that doesn't explain why it suddenly *disengaged* (against the force of the springs that should be holding the plates together) while you were driving. If the springs have broken, I can't think of an "emergency repair".